# Как правильно сверстать сетку?

Tags: html, css

Вот такую:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается у большой картинки `66.666%`,
У маленьких `33.333%`.

Comment: Посмотрите как сделано там где вы это увидели - в исходном коде странички.
Вы можете сохранять странички к себе и рассматривать их в качестве информации.
Смотря что есть сможете сделать как то по своему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
div.container {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
div.container div.item {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: #FFF 1px solid;
}
div.container div.item:first-child {
  width: 66.66%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
</div>
```